# How to get the type of a function on runtime that returns a prisma findFirst operation

Tags: typescript, types, prisma

I'm trying to create a function like this

```
export async function retrieveUser(userConditions: Prisma.UserFindFirstArgs) {

    return await prisma.user.findFirst(userConditions)

}
```

When I execute the function:

```
const user = await retrieveUser({ include: { bar: true }})
```

my problem is that if I try to type `user.bar` typescript informs me that 'Property 'bar' does not exist on type...' but if I execute

```
const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
    include: { bar: true }
})
```

then user has a bar property included.

I tried to create a function that retrieves the users with some condition specified on run time but  I can't manage to return a type with all the relations, just like `prisma.user.findFirst({ include: { bar: true } })`  does.

I would like to find a way to make my function `retrieveUser` to behave just like `prisma.user.findFirst` does when returning a type.

My function should be able to work with every include/select so I don't want to create a type with Prisma.Validator or such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question. Would something like this do what you want?

```
export async function retrieveUser<T extends Prisma.UserFindFirstArgs>(
  userConditions: T
): Promise<Prisma.UserGetPayload<T>> {
  return await prisma.user.findFirst(userConditions);
}
```

You could then use this function like this.

```
// Example usage with include
const userWithBar = await retrieveUser({ include: { bar: true } });

// Example usage with select
const userWithSelectedFields = await retrieveUser({ select: { id: true, name: true } });
```

In this function, `T` is a generic type that extends `Prisma.UserFindFirstArgs`, which means it can accept any valid argument for the `findFirst` method. `risma.UserGetPayload<T>` is a utility type from Prisma that will infer the return type based on the include or select options provided.

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for the response, it finally works. I was so close yet so far, but finally the types are correctly inferred. The only thing is that typescript gives me an error on the return line of the retrieveUser function. I'll link an image on the twitter thread for bettere explanation. Except for that it works perfectly!
[twitter thead](https://twitter.com/LnrdRmj/status/1752418871196430474)